# JBoss7 and Beans - required jars appear not to be used

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, javabeans, jboss7.x

We are trying to create a functional example with Hibernate, JBoss7, Beans and Servlets using Eclipse as an IDE. 
In other example project we were able to make functional Servlets, and we were able to use Hibernate.

We created two eclipse projects:
A Dynamic web project, an Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) project and a EAR project connecting both.

Running a simple test.java file which uses hibernate (and worked on other projects), we the get errors:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at exercicio.SessionFactoryUtil.<clinit>(SessionFactoryUtil.java:20)
    at exercicio.DataBaseInterface.<init>(DataBaseInterface.java:17)
    at exercicio.Test.main(Test.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at exercicio.SessionFactoryUtil.configureSessionFactory(SessionFactoryUtil.java:32)
    at exercicio.SessionFactoryUtil.<clinit>(SessionFactoryUtil.java:17)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 19 more
```

The problem now seems to be around the jars that we included using project Properties > Java Build Path > Add External Jars for the EJB project:

We added the slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar and hibernate jars but the exception log appears to be indicating that we are still missing some jar.

If we remove the jars from the Java Build Path, the exception log is the same. So we think that the jars are not being deployed correctly, or some extra configuration is required... even thought they appear in the /lib folder inside the EJB project deployment folder.

Is there any procedure we are missing, or any probable causes to investigate? I'll add more info if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When using JBoss7 not all Jars are available to the application by default (for example slf4j). You have to specify which modules should be included in the classpath of the application by putting this information into a file in your application.

I always do it by adding `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` into my application (the EAR in your case).

Here's how https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7.
(The name of the module in your case would be `org.slf4j`)

Answer (score 1):

Throwing slf4j jar in the libs folder can create a conflict with the slf4j module already included in JB7 by default... you have to add the dependency to your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

But if your hibernate jars are in the libs folder, they could fail resolve the dependency as well too... the way to go in JB7 would be to make a module for Hibernate too, the Nightie builds of JB7 already include an hibernate module, you could just copy the module from there, then add it to your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`